# Does the greeting "Good Yom Tov" contain a redundancy?

Tags: blessing, hebrew, yom-tov

Does the greeting "Good Yom Tov" contain a redundancy? Doesn't "Yom Tov" mean "Good day"? So you are saying "Good good day?"

Comment: The "Tov" means that the day in general is good. The "good" means that I hope your particular experience on this day is good and enjoyable.

Comment: Tov Yom Good to you too!

Comment: Note that idioms do not need to be literally correct. This is an idiom for *Have a good ho(i/y)day*

Answer (score 8):

This is a matter of idiom. "Yom Tov" while literally meaning "Good Day" is the idiom for a day that is "good" because of the spiritual level of that day. Thus, when spoken as a single phrase, the translation is similar to the English original "Holy Day" which we now use as "holiday". The Yiddish "Yumtuf" or "Yuntif" shows that it is used a a single meaning. Thus "Good Yuntif" would not be considered a redundancy. It is the equivalent of "Happy Holiday".

This answer was approved by the Department of Redundancy department (:-)

Comment: Funny ... I hope people saw the humor in the question, as well. You didn't think I was 100% serious, did you?

Comment: @DanF What else would your question be except serious?

Comment: @DanF What do the Jews in Rome say to the Pope on Shavuos?

Comment: @DanF Gut Yuntif Puntif

Answer (score 4):

In Munkatch the custom is to say just Yom-Tov and not 'Git' Yom-Tov.

The Rebbe of Munkatch used to say that Git Yom Tuv is one of three redundant expressions in yiddish:

גוט יום טוב

מים אחרונים וואסער

אונגארישער נער

Comment: Maybe the Munkatcher rebbe also noted that the phrase "Shabbat Hol Hamo'ed" is a double oximoron?

Comment: The last expression, when heard, might be assumed to mean "a young fool".